# Replace Div content onclick menu with Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, replace, replacewith

I'm trying to create a menu where it replaces the content inside with another div already created, but currently set to hidden. I know of other methods to do this, but they are not very clean.

[What I currently have done](http://students.washington.edu/chris480/practice/menu.html).
The current code in which I'm trying to use:

```
   function switchDiv(content){
   $("#Phrase")hide().replaceWith($("#" + content).css("visibility", "visible").fadeIn("slow"));
   }
```

I'm trying to replicate the concept of another site I found on another post. Where text is stored in an array and then replaced using:

```
    $("#menu-sub-menu > ul > li[id^=d]").click(function() {
        $("#defined").hide().html(Phrases[$(this).index()]).fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

But I wish to replace more than just text.

Also, if anyone knows what this kind of menu is called, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because after the first click, you are replacing all the content of `#Phrase` with the one phrase you are keeping.

Take all of the `test` `div`'s and put them somewhere other than the `#phrase` `div` initially.

Also - you don't want to use `replaceWith`.  That will remove the `#Phrase` `div` and you won't be able to hide it again.  Un-chaining your jquery commands may help you get to where you want first, and then re-chain them if you so please.